# Explain why it makes sense that the rate of change of the area increases as the area increases.

Tags: calculus

The question is as follows ; A rock dropped into a pond causes a circular wave of ripples whose radius increases at $6$ inches per second. How fast is the area of the circle of ripples expanding at the instant that the area of the circle is $100$ square inches? $200$ square inches? $1000$ square inches? Explain why it makes sense that the rate of change of the area increases as the area increases.

I understand the general idea hear, if i'm not mistaken. The first step is to find the equation that gives you the relationship between the radius and area the circle. Then you plug a few numbers somewhere, and should get some answers. But i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that the area of the circular ripple is $A=\pi r^2$

$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=2\pi r\dfrac{dr}{dt}$

From the question we have, $\dfrac{dr}{dt}=6$ inches per second

So, the rate of change of area with respect to time is $$\dfrac{dA}{dt}=2\pi r(6)=12\pi r$$

Now, to find the rates of areas with the radius you have, you need to plug in the values of $r$ in the above area rate equation.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Could you clarity how i get the multiple values of r you mentioned, that i would plug into the rate equation. So i'm given 100, 200,1000  as area values now i take these values and plug them into which equation to get r's?

Comment: @isthewiz Yes, that is what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a small ring and a large ring.

If both of them have the same thickness but one has a larger radius the one with the larger radius has also the larger area.

The rate at which the area increases is just a ring around the circle with the thickness being the rate of increase of the radius.

I have avoided formulas to not make you nervous. Think about it and you will get it easily.